# Windows 8.1 update effectively disabled mobile broadband connection

Tags: windows-8.1

I have Windows 8.1 on my HP laptop and a Huawei broadband modem which was working fine but since some of the updates of Windows 8.1 it is now not working.

I have following issue: Under `Device Manager` > `Network Adaptor` it shows the Hauwei mobile E303H but when I click on it and go to the Driver tab I can see that no device driver is installed.

When I click to update the driver and select the generic mobile broadband adaptor it fails and shows "access denied".

How do I go about replacing the driver for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a result of using the class driver for the module. I don't think it's a driver issue. I recommend testing disabling the "selective suspend" setting which could be causing the port to become effectively disconnected.

I've worked with OEM's and mobile broadband companies on similar issues. If the port that the modem communicates on becomes idle for a certain period of time it can be suspended. Try this before trying to alter any drivers.

Follow the steps from this article: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/windows-81-mobile-broadband-problem-samsung-ativ/3d05c37f-c966-499a-b5f3-3682ddb26c5e